# Installing new extensions in Magento 2.0.7

Tags: magento, cron

I've been trying to install a new extension for a while now in Magento 2.0.7, but try as I might, I can't get the new extension to show up under Component Manager (despite having uploaded the extracted extension files to the right directory). Any ideas why this might be happening?

I initially tried to install the extension by "syncing" with my Marketplace purchases, but the "sync wheel" simply keeps spinning and hands when I attempt to sync. Not quite sure why that is happening - that would seem to be the best way to install, but I couldnt get it done that way, so tried doing it manually.

I'm also getting a "One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running" error in the Magento admin area. Not sure if that is related to this, but upon researching it seems that this is vitally important to take care of, so I set up Cron jobs in cpanel as per https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/optimization-and-configuration/magento1/optimizing-magento-cron-jobs-on-shared-hosting-accounts (I'm not using their hosting though).

No dice on any of that, tho ... I'm wondering if someone can help me out here?? Apologies for the verbose nature of this post - just wanted to make sure I explain everything at one shot ...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Magento compiler - or if you are not sure if you're doing so - log into the Magento backend and go to System > Tools > Compilation and turn it off.  try to ENABLE the cache at System > Cache Management before installing any extension.
Go to System > Cache Management and click both the 'Flush Magento Cache' as well as the 'Flush Cache Storage' button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files of the extension are already in place, enable the extension by clearing the static content (do not forget to replace `<extension_name>` with the name of your extension):

```
php bin/magento module:enable <extension_name> --clear-static-content
```

Update Magento:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Finally, if needed, deploy the static view files:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```